# button:hover:before not clickable in Firefox

Tags: css

This code works in Chrome, the cursor appears as a pointer and registering the click event as it should, but not in Firefox. Can you tell my why?

```css
@import url('https://rawcdn.githack.com/WordPress/dashicons/242e2712334e30648b328e91c44366d55ef2146a/icon-font/css/dashicons.css');

button.slick-arrow,
button.slick-arrow:hover,
button.slick-arrow:focus {
    background: none !important;
    text-indent: initial;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    vertical-align: top;
    font-size: 0;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border: none;
}
button.slick-arrow:before {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    font: normal 32px/1 'dashicons';
    padding: 8px;
    opacity: 0.6;
    color: #000;
    cursor: pointer;
}
button.slick-arrow:hover:before {
    opacity: 1;
}
button.slick-prev:before {
    content: "\f341";
    left: 8px;
}
button.slick-next:before {
    content: "\f345";
    right: 8px;
}
```

```html
<button class="slick-prev slick-arrow">Click me!</button>
```

Comment: you will may find this interesting too: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-smooth

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue lays within the positioning of your before element. Since it is positioned absolutely, and the button itself has it's width and height set to 0, the element size is zero, and you cannot interact with it.

To fix this, remove `width: 0;` and `height: 0;` from the button, and remove the `position: absolute;` from the `:before`-pseudo.

Additionally, add `cursor: pointer;` to your button.

```css
@import url('https://rawcdn.githack.com/WordPress/dashicons/242e2712334e30648b328e91c44366d55ef2146a/icon-font/css/dashicons.css');

button.slick-arrow,
button.slick-arrow:hover,
button.slick-arrow:focus {
    background: none !important;
    text-indent: initial;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    vertical-align: top;
    font-size: 0;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
button.slick-arrow:before {
    display: block;
    font: normal 32px/1 'dashicons';
    padding: 8px;
    opacity: 0.6;
    color: #000;
}
button.slick-arrow:hover:before {
    opacity: 1;
}
button.slick-prev:before {
    content: "\f341";
    left: 8px;
}
button.slick-next:before {
    content: "\f345";
    right: 8px;
}
```

```html
<button class="slick-arrow slick-prev">Click me!</button>
```